# Entity that references itself returning stack overflow error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a RESTful api for an application. One of the resources is a `Category` which is capable of having any n number of subcategories. This relationship is determined by an entity which references itself by a one-to-many relationship, and vice versa. The following is the entity, DAO, DTO, and controller for the Category resource of the API:

CategoryResponse.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategoryResponse {

    Long id;

    String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    List<CategoryResponse> subCategories;
    
}
```

Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Builder
public class Category extends AuditedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = true)
    Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Category> subCategories;
    
}
```

CategoryRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepo extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {

    Iterable<Category> findByDeletedOnIsNull();

    Optional<Category> findByIdAndDeletedOnIsNull(Long id);

    Iterable<Category> findByParentCategoryIsNullAndDeletedOnIsNull();

    Iterable<Category> findByParentCategoryIdAndDeletedOnIsNull(Long id);
    
}
```

CategoryDAO.java

```
@Service
public class CategoryDAO {

    @Autowired
    CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    public Iterable<Category> findAll() {

        Iterable<Category> result = categoryRepo.findByDeletedOnIsNull();

        return result;

    }

    public Iterable<Category> findAllParentCategories() {

        Iterable<Category> result = categoryRepo.findByParentCategoryIsNullAndDeletedOnIsNull();

        return result;

    }

    public Iterable<Category> findAllSubCategories(Long id) {

        Iterable<Category> result = categoryRepo.findByParentCategoryIdAndDeletedOnIsNull(id);

        return result;
        
    }

    public Optional<Category> findById(Long id) {

        Optional<Category> result = categoryRepo.findByIdAndDeletedOnIsNull(id);

        return result;

    }
    
}
```

CategoryController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/category")
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(
        produces = "application/json"
    )
    ResponseEntity<Iterable<CategoryResponse>> index() {

        Iterable<Category> categories = categoryDAO.findAllParentCategories();
        List<CategoryResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Category category : categories) {

            CategoryResponse response = new CategoryResponse(category);
            
            if(response.getSubCategories() != null) {
                
                List<CategoryResponse> subResponses = new ArrayList<>();
                
                for(Category subCategory : category.getSubCategories()) {
                    
                    CategoryResponse subResponse = new CategoryResponse(subCategory);
                    subResponses.add(subResponse);
                    
                }
                
                response.setSubCategories(subResponses);
                
            }
            
            responses.add(response);

        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responses, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

I would suspect that when I make the following API call, I would get a list of all categories and subcategories in the database, however instead I get a stack overflow error. Why might this be happening? The following is the web request, response, and the output the application makes to the console:

Raw Request

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/category HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)
```

Raw Response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 20:27:36 GMT
Connection: close

{"timestamp":"2022-03-03T20:27:36.804+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","trace":"java.lang.StackOverflowError\n\tat java.base/java.lang.System$2.encodeASCII(System.java:2414)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:456)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:564)\n\tat java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:585)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:293)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:132)\n\tat java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:205)\n\tat java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120)\n\tat java.base/java.io.PrintStream.writeln(PrintStream.java:722)\n\tat java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1028)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:147)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:125)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:170)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:198)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:162)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2217)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:595)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458)\n\tat com.yuknis.ziwi.ziwidataservice.category.entity.Category.hashCode(Category.java:28)\n\tat com.yuknis.ziwi.ziwidataservice.category.entity.Category.hashCode(Category.java:28)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:610)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:232)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:190)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2217)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:595)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458)\n\tat com.yuknis.ziwi.ziwidataservice.category.entity.Category.hashCode(Category.java:28)\n\tat com.yuknis.ziwi.ziwidataservice.category.entity.Category.hashCode(Category.java:28)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:610)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:232)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:190)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2217)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:595)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458)\n\tat com.yuknis.ziwi.ziwidataservice.category.entity.Category.hashCode(Category.java:28)\n\tat com.yuknis.ziwi.ziwidataservice.category.entity.Category.hashCode(Category.java:28)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:610)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:232)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:190)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105)\n\ta
```

Comment: The `@JsonBackReference`metnioned in your link seems to have solved the error issue, however it results in the subCategories not being serialized. How might I be able to serialize the DAO, with parent and sub categories serialized?

Comment: I was able to get the result I desired by making a CategoryResponse and SubCategoryResponse type, then changing the subCategories property to the other class, but there are now two classes doing basically the same exact thing? is there a better way of doing this?